# Check if the clicked link's href does not start with a hash tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

This is how I can select all links whose href's don't start with a `#`:

```
$('a:not([href^="#"])')
```

But how can I determine whether a link has a href that starts with a hash tag or not **AFTER** it's clicked? This fails:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
   if($(this).is('[href^="#"])')) {
     alert('No hash');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You removed the `:not()` from your selector. Put it back and it should work.

```
if($(this).is('a:not([href^="#"])')) {
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/8An48/

---

Or better...

```
if (this.getAttribute("href").charAt(0) !== "#") {
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/8An48/1/

---

Or use event delegation from the nearest ancestor that contains all the `a` elements being targeted.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a:not([href^="#"])', function() {
     alert('No hash');
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/8An48/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
   if(($(this).attr('href').substr(0,1)) != '#') {
     alert('No hash');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
   if($(this).attr("href").indexOf("#") === -1) {
     alert('No hash');
   }
});
```

Explanation

`$(this).attr("href")` - gets the value of the href attribute of the clicked link

`.indexOf("#")` - this will return the position of string B if string A contains it. Otherwise it returns false

`=== -1` - the triple equals and the `-1` ensures that this is 100% false (and not equal to a string or a number)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()`.

```
$('a').filter(function(){
  return this.href.slice(0, 1) !== '#';
}).addClass('does-not-start-with-hash');
```